# How do I refactor my controllers.js so I have each controller in a separate file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building an app using Ionic Framework and AngularJS 1x.

My system info:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.2.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1
OS: Distributor ID: LinuxMint Description:  Linux Mint 18 Sarah 
Node Version: v4.2.6
```

I have a controllers.js file with all my controllers. however my app has become complex and the controllers.js file is now ~900 lines. I want to separate the controllers into their own files eg firstCtrl.js secondCtrl.js etc. I have googled for a while now but can't find anything. The only refactoring examples I could find are where the tutorial has everything in app.js and they refactor to controllers.js

**app.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'ngOpenFB', 'firebase', 'angularMoment', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives', 'app.filters'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform, ngFB, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $cordovaLocalNotification) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

  // code code code....

  });
})
```

**controllers.js**

```
angular.module('app.controllers', ['ngCordova'])

.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {
    // awesome code...

})

.controller('secondCtrl', function($scope) {
    // awesome code...

})

.controller('thirdCtrl', function($scope) {
    // awesome code...

});
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/routes.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
<script src="js/filters.js"></script>
```

How can I separate out my controllers into individual .js files for each controller?

Comment: I would suggest to have a look to a couple of guides about how to structure angular code. Here are a couple of them: [this](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) and [this](https://github.com/gocardless/angularjs-style-guide).

Answer (score 4):

**firstCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {
    // awesome code...
})
```

**secondCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('app.controllers')
.controller('secondCtrl', function($scope) {
    // awesome code...
})
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/firstCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/secondCtrl.js"></script>
```

Comment: it's not working, I am getting an error saying: "ionic.bundle.js:25642 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'firstCtrl' is not a function, got undefined"

Comment: @chmod777 In your `app.js` add `angular.module('app.controllers', []);`

Comment: ad it where exactly? I added it to the bottom of app.js but I still get the error message as above

Answer (score 1):

Just like @Weedoze said or take a refrence form the angular object

`var app =angular.module('app.controllers')` and start to attach your controller below

```
app.controller('XCtrl', function($scope) {

})
```